# Difference between Fabric Canvas and StaticCanvas

Tags: fabricjs

Can anyone explain the difference and purpose of Canvas and Static Canvas in Fabric JS. I'm really confused with the both topic!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`StaticCanvas` [has no interactive layer and no event handling](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#interactivity). You can't drag objects around, draw, register clicks, etc.

`StaticCanvas` is used when you only need to render a scene or when handling user interaction is impossible, e.g. rendering canvas on the server side.